# Subversion: why "mixed revisions" when revision numbers are sequential?

Tags: svn

An example: Say that after an `svn update` I am on revision 10. If I now add a file and perform a commit, svnversion will report that I am in a state of mixed revisions; namely 10:11. But since these numbers are in sequence, clearly there has not been any other commit in between. Couldn't subversion deduct from this that my version is up to date (=HEAD) so I wouldn't need to run another svn update in order to remove this mixed revisions state?

I realize this is no big deal; I just wonder if I am missing some special case were the above reasoning may not be true.

Comment: I've never accidentally created a "mixed revisions" state just by committing new files. Then again I use TortoiseSVN and usually perform the commit operation on the project root. Maybe that way it figures out the entire thing is up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually a bit surprised that Subversion claims that your modified files are version 11, because they might not be. If somebody else were to commit a version 11 before you, then your files would end up being version 12 or greater.

I guess the reason is that your local subversion can't claim that your version with added files is fully version 11, because it doesn't know for sure yet.

Comment: The scenario I tried to describe above is that nobody has commited a version between my "update" and later "commit", and that subversion should be able to deduce that since the version numbers are in sequence. Of course, if someone HAD committed something before me, then I would get version 12 (or later) and the "mixed revision" state would be justified.

Comment: But your local Subversion doesn't know that nobody else has committed anything, without talking to the server.

Comment: Are you saying that my local Subversion isn't talking to the server when i do a Commit?

Comment: Sorry, I must have misread what you said. (Either that, or I've been using Git too long.) Of course you're right, the client does talk to the server when doing a commit. But I guess it doesn't necessarily know about the status of the rest of the files without doing an `svn update`.

Comment: Exactly :) My point is that in this particular case Subversion actually DOES now the status of the rest of the files; it just does not make use of it.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your issue right, I can tell you that your working copy will almost always have mixed-revisions. This is because different files have been committed in different revisions and have changed then. Have you noticed that some files (for e.g.) show revision 10 and others 25, but yet you're still in the HEAD revision. This is because your workspace holds additional metadata for the files and revisions.

Generally this should not be a problem at all and as far as I am concerned it is part of the SVN workflow. I recall that this is explained somewhere in the SVN documentation but I can't seem to find it right now. I will edit my answer accordingly if I do so.